# Establishing chronology of a list based on a directed graph tree

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-algorithm

So, in a personal project I've been working on I came across a following problem, and I've been struggling to come up with a solution since my maths skills are not terribly great.

Lets say you have a following tree of numbers a b c d e f g h:

```
    a
   / \
   b  c
 / |  |
g  d  f
|  |
h  e
```

Each step down the tree means that the next number is bigger then the previous one. So a < b, d < e, a < c. However, it is impossible to determine whether b > c or c < b - we can only tell that both numbers are bigger then a.

Lets say we have an ordered list of numbers, for instance [a, b, c, d, e]. How do we write an algorithm that checks if the order of the numbers in the list (assuming that L[i] < L[i+1]) is, in fact, correct in relation to the information we have accoring to this tree?

I. E, both [a, c, b, d, e] and [a, b, d, c, e] are correct, but [c, a, b, d, e] is not (since we know that c > a but nothing else in relation to how the other numbers are structured).

For the sake of the algorithm, lets assume that our access to the tree is a function provably_greater(X, Y) which returns true if the tree knows that a number is higher then another number. I.E. provably_greater(a, d) = True, but provably_greater(d, f) = False. Naturally if a number is provably not greater, it also returns false.

This is *not* a homework question, I have abstracted the problem quite a lot to make it more clear, but solving this problem is quite crucial for what I'm trying to do. I've made several attempts at cracking it myself, but everything that I come up with ends up being insufficient for some edge case I find out about later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you just loop through the array and compare each entry with the next using your function?

Comment: See, I tried that but it works only in the case of a tree that does not have any branching. For instance, [a, b, d, c, e] would be detected as an incorrect list, because its impossible to prove that d < c, from the tree, although the tree does not disprove it either (and hence it is a possibility and the list should be correct).

Comment: By restricting access to the tree (which is a heap, b.t.w) to the provably_greater function, you eliminate all the efficient algorithms I can think of.  Is this restriction real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement "everything that I come up with ends up being insufficient for some edge case I find out about later" makes it seem that you have no solution at all. Here is **a brute-force algorithm** that should work in all cases. I can think of several possible ways to improve the speed, but this is a start.

First, set up a data structure that allows a quick evaluation of `provably_greater(X, Y)` based on the tree. This structure can be a set or hash-table, which will take much memory but allow fast access. For each leaf of the tree, take a path up to the root. At each node, look at all descendant nodes and add an ordered pair to the set that shows the less-than relation for those two nodes. In your example tree, if you start at node `h` you move up to node `g` and add `(g,h)` to the set, then move up to node `b` and add the pairs `(b,h)` and `(b,g)` to the set, then move up to node `a` and add the pairs `(a,h)`, `(a,g)`, and `(a,b)` to the set. Do the same for leaf nodes `e` and `f`. The pair `(a,b)` will be added twice to the set, due to the leaf nodes `h` and `e`, but a set structure can handle this easily.

The function `provably_greater(X, Y)` is now quick and easy: the result is `True` if the pair `(Y,X)` is in the set and `False` otherwise.

You now look at all pairs of numbers in your list--for the list `[a,b,c,d,e]` you would look at the pairs `(a,b)`, `(a,c)`, `(b,c)`, etc.  If `provably_greater(X, Y)` is true for any of those pairs, the list is out of order. Otherwise, the list is in order.

This should be very easy to implement in a language like Python. Let me know if you would like some Python 3 code.

Comment: I actually had a provably_greater already implemented, but I somehow did not even think that simply checking that  every two subsequent numbers are not provably smaller would do the trick! It seems so obvious in retrospect. I tried it and it seems to be working quite nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore your provably_greater function and assume access to the tree so that I can provide an efficient algorithm.

1. First, perform a Euler tour of the tree, remembering the start and end indexes for every node.  If you use the same tree to check a lot of lists, you only have to do this once.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euler-tour-tree/
2. Create an initially empty binary search tree of indexes
3. Iterate through the list.  For each node, check to see if the tree contains any indexes between its start and end Euler tour indexes.  If it does, then the list is out of order.  If it does not, then insert its start index into the tree.  This will prevent any provably lesser node from appearing later in the list.

That's it -- O(N log N) altogether, and for each list.

A `TreeSet` in Java or `std::set` in C++ can be used for the binary search tree.

Comment: I know that the term "Euler tour" is used in the linked page, but this seems to be the wrong use for that term. I believe that an [Euler tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) usually means a path through the structure that uses each edge exactly once. The structure you use is more commonly called a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: @RoryDaulton  That's a Eulerian path through a graph.  Not the same thing.  The important point about the Euler tour is that each node is visited on entry *and* exit.  Otherwise yes, it is a DFS

Comment: @RoryDaulton if it helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique  I'm not terribly fond of the name clash, but this technique is used in several great algorithms.  It needs a name and this is the one the community seems to have settled on.

Comment: Now that I found [this explanation of "Euler tour technique"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique) I understand. --It seems that you pointed me to that page seconds before I told you that I found the page. It's all good--thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The restriction wasn't actually neccesary (just for explanations sake), and thanks for the efficient implmentation. I've marked the other answer as solved since bruteforce is sufficent for now, but if that ever changes I will give your algorithm a shot. Thanks!